# How to refresh the Datagrid in Flex 4?

Tags: datagrid, flex4.5

I am using ArrayCollection as the dataprovider to my datagrid and retrieving the information from MySQL using JSP and adding them to the ArrayCollection. I would like to transfer the selected item from one datagrid to other datagrid by changing the status of the file. As of know, am able to do this fine but I need to refresh the webpage manually for the updated results in both the datagrids.

I tried to do the following thing : dataGrid.invalidateDisplayList()

I called this method on both the datagrid's but it's not refreshing the datagrid, I still need to refresh my webpage for the updated results. Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to refresh the DataGrid.

Just make your ArrayCollection variable  Bindable which is your dataprovider of DataGrid.
So, whenever you will make a change in your dataprovider(ArrayCollection) and it will be reflected on your DataGrid automatically.

Comment: Yes, I already set the ArrayCollection as Bindable but am extracting details from the database using JSP and then binding it to the DataGrid. So, I think I need to call even hadler to refresh the datagrid manually.